# Draw extruded 3d text with pyopengl?

Tags: python, 3d, freetype, pyopengl, truetype

What is the best way to draw 3d text with pyopengl, preferably with modern opengl ?

There seem to be quite a few examples, but mostly in old-style opengl and not for python

Comment: You mean 2D text in a 3D room or text with a 3D body?

Comment: Taking a truetype font and turning it into a 3d model, like this  http://s3.amazonaws.com/pbblogassets/uploads/2013/04/3D-Menu-Text.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need a text outline which requires a font.
   On windows you can use [WinGDI fonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by [creating a dummy context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [selecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a [created font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it and [getting outlines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of every character. For [Truetype](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html) you [load glyphs](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html#section-6) into the face and simply [access](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_GlyphSlotRec) their outlines.
2. For the front & back face of your 3D text, you need to convert the outlines/contours to triangles. Either use the good old [GLU tesselator](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html), the relative new [tesselation shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation) of OpenGL 4 or a geometry library like [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). Then simply draw the triangles for the front and again with some additional depth for the back.
3. For the sides you simply span rectangles behind outline segments/lines with *height* equal to your wished text depth - these are your text sides. You can simply use a depth vector and transform everything afterwards or calculate the orthogonal vector with 2 segments.

You notice that this all can be expensive, so don't hesitate to cache as much as possible.

I referenced to C sources because i'm more familiar with these, but i bet there're python equivalents to port my explanations.

Comment: Cheers for the detailed answer, I need to come back to this and actually implement it....   the GetGlyphOutline hint is good, it looks like there is a cross platform equivalent in cairo with cairo_glyph_path(), freetype looks like a sensible option for outlines too.